# Check if an url string gives back a valid webpage.

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimage, nsdate, nsurl

How can I check if an image-url-string gives back a valid url? 
I'm talking about this url http://rscagen3t004-dev.tdlinx.dev/sites/all/themes/rsca/resources/images/RSCA_logo.png

You can see when you click on the link that the webpage is not available. At the moment I'm doing this in my code:

```
 if([meta.met_thumb hasPrefix:@"http://"]){
                imgURL = meta.met_thumb;


                NSData *walImage = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]];
                NSLog(@"walImage is %@",walImage);
                float newHeight2;
                if (walImage != nil) {
                    UIImage *imgIcon = [UIImage imageWithData:walImage];
                    if (imgIcon != nil) {
                        float width = imgIcon.size.width;
                        float heigt = imgIcon.size.height;
                        if(heigt < 240){
                            float newWidth = (heigt / 240);
                            float newWidht2 = (newWidth/ width);
                            //[imgNews setFrame:CGRectMake(40,y, newWidht2,heigt)];
                        }
                        float newHeight =  (width / 240);
                        newHeight2 = heigt/ newHeight;
                    }else{
                        newHeight2 = 240;
                    }

                }else{
                    newHeight2 = 240;
                }


                height = [self heightForStatus:attString] + y + newHeight2 + 70;
            }else{
                height = [self heightForStatus:attString] + y + 240 + 70;
            }
```

But it takes a very long time to execute the line of the `[[NSData alloc] init]`.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What does you mean saying "valid URL"? In your code you do not test, whether the URL is valid, but download an image.

Comment: like you see when you click on the link. It does not give an image back it says "Webpage not available"

Comment: An URL that is "valid" does neither mean that the server can response nor that the response is fast. Put the code in background.

Answer (score 0):

The long delay in executing the line with `alloc/init` is probably caused by the slow response of the server. I just tested and after 30 seconds I neither got the image nor the error page.

To detect a "valid URL" you should check the server response. It should give a proper response of 404 = not found. Also see http response codes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

So what you should do is check wether you get a 404 or the according 2xx response. Then decide if you have data and create your image. Still, that may go wrong, if for example no image data is received but a web page.

Comment: And how do I do that ?

Comment: I won't write code, and there are various ways of achieving that. All you need is covered in detail in documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i